# Get a contact's groups?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a many-to-many mapping of contacts to groups.

For example, if I have:

- User 1, belongs to group 701, 702, 704
- User 2, belongs to no groups
- User 3, belongs to group 702

I'm hoping to get a relation that looks like this:

```
userID | groupID
1      | 701
1      | 702
1      | 704
3      | 702
```

I've tried this:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, new String[] {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_SOURCE_ID
}, null, null, null);
```

But that doesn't quite work. The GROUP_SOURCE_ID column returns weird numbers that aren't the ID of any groups. Sometimes it even returns 0 or a negative number.

I could construct a mapping of this by going through each group, and finding all contacts in that group, but that would take a lot of queries, and I'm trying to stay fast (apparently, just those few queries are quite slow!).

Can anyone tell me how I can get this contacts-to-groups mapping in one query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
    Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
            },
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null
    );
```

By using this `dataCursor` you will get the `contact_id` and `group_id` of all contacts in the contact database.

```
    Cursor groupCursor = getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{
                    ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                    ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
            }, null, null, null
    );
```

By using this `groupCursor` you will get the `group_id` and `group_title` of all groups in the contact database.

So if you want to get all groups associated with a `contact_id` the first get the `dataCursor` using suitable select statements. Using `dataCursor` you can get all the `group_id` associated with that `contact_id`. Now using `groupCursor` you can get the information about all groups associated with that specific contact.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much!

So how did you know that I needed DATA1? Are there any docs that could have told me the solution? Because I looked for a long time, and couldn't find any...

Comment: @Verdagon By examining the contact database

Comment: Is this something a newbie should be able to do? If not, can you tell me how, and I can write an article on it or something?

Comment: Simply get the database from `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/database` and open it using `sqliteman` or other softwares. Now you will be able to see the data inside it. Looking at the data you can say which column you will need.

Answer (score 3):

A complete answer will be:
First the fetch the group cursor (same as the answer above)

```
Cursor groups_cursor= getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Groups._ID,
                ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE
        }, null, null, null
);
```

Store all the group_id and group_title in a groups HashMap using this code:

```
 if(groups_cursor!=null){
        while(groups_cursor.moveToNext()){
            String group_title = groups_cursor.getString(1);
            String id = groups_cursor.getString(0);
            groups.put(id, group_title);
        }
    }
```

Then using the above answer's data_cursor, fetch contacts_ids and their group_ids.

```
Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[]{
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.Data.DATA1
        },
        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?",
        new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE}, null
);
```

Now using the dataCursor and the groups HashMap.

```
    if(dataCursor!=null){
            while(dataCursor.moveToNext()){
                String id  = dataCursor.getString(0);
                String group_id= dataCursor.getString(1);
                String groupTitle = groups.get(group_id);
                Log.d(TAG, "groupTitle : " + groupTitle + " contact_id: " + id );
           }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static HashMap<String, String> getContactsForGroup(String groupID, Activity activity){
    Cursor dataCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{                                                       // PROJECTION
                    ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                    ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME,         // contact name
                    ContactsContract.Data.DATA1                 // group
            },
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? " + "AND " +                 // SELECTION
            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 +    " = ? ",           // set groupID
            new String[]{                                                       // SELECTION_ARGS
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                    groupID
            },
            null
    );

    dataCursor.moveToFirst();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (dataCursor.moveToNext()) //
    {
        String s0 = dataCursor.getString(0);                //contact_id
        String s1 = dataCursor.getString(1);                //contact_name
        String s2 = dataCursor.getString(2);                //group_id
        Log.d("tag", "contact_id: " + s0 + "  contact: " + s1 + "   groupID: "+ s2);
        map.put(s0, s1);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: A few suggestions... change your `while` loop to a `do while` loop.  As the code is written now, it will always skip the first row of the table because `cursor.moveToFirst()` puts the pointer at index 0 but `while (cursor.moveToNext())` will advance it to index 1.  You should `close()` the cursor (ie with a try finally block).  Finally  `dataCursor.moveToFirst()` could theoretically throw a NPE, so add a null check.