# How to get Group ID of contacts Number (Android)

Tags: java, android, sql, call, contacts

How to **get Group ID knowing contact's Number**

I guess it have to be another query inside this one, but I have not ANY idea how to do it

Here what I've tried:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{ ContactsContract.Groups._ID };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER +" = "+ number,
        null,
        null);

cursor.moveToNext();
String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Groups._ID));
```

*(Query returns nothing)*

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3):

Your query returns nothing, because there is no such column `Groups._ID` within dataset `CommonDataKinds.Phone`.

Try something like this:

```
String sPhoneNumber = "+48123456789";    
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership._ID}, 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"='"+sPhoneNumber+"'", null, null);
```

where `sPhoneNumber` is String with desired phone number. Keep in mind, that your cursor may still return 0 depending on:

1. how your phone number is formatted, i.e. you wish to find group ID
   for contact of given number `+49123456789` while number is formatted
   like this `+49 123 456 789`. Whitespaces are making this completely 
   different `String`.
2. your contact does not belong to any group.

Also cursor can still return more results, mostly in cases when your contact belongs to more than one group.

Comment: Lonti84, thanks for reply! I already solved this problem.. maybe not in so elegant way. I can't test your answer right now as I have a lot of things to do, but I'll test it ASAP. TNX!

Comment: @Inoy Today I was dealing with similar problem (retrieve group ID base on contact name) and i've noticed it was not so simple like i posted here. my working solution was based on this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097582/get-a-contacts-groups)