# Contact fetcher not showing home category mobile in the list android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch the contacts using cursor loader in background. But I noticed that when a particular user has their contact in home category, its not showing in my list. Only mobile category contacts are showing up.

I am using the following method :

```
public void fetchAll() {
        HashMap<String, String> hmContacts = new HashMap<>();

        String[] projectionFields = new String[]{
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
        };

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(context,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projectionFields,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        Cursor c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

            do {
                String number = Validator.formatNumbers(c.getString(idIndex));
                String name = c.getString(nameIndex);
                if (number.length() != 10)
                    continue;
                hmContacts.put(number, name);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            WoofyApp.getApp().setPersons(hmContacts);
        }
        c.close();
    }
```

Comment: Is it just for home category or any category?

Comment: @klauskpm I haven't tried with other categories but pretty sure they won't be showing as well.. only mobile category is showing up

Comment: I think you need to do these two steps: [Get a contacts group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14097582/get-a-contacts-groups) and then [Get a list of contacts that belongs to a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403377/android-get-list-of-contacts-belonging-to-a-specific-group)

Comment: @klauskpm as far as I know.. shouldn't this method fetch contacts from every category..or am I missing something here?

Comment: Since I'm a newbie at Android, I can't say for sure. It seems it shouldn't need it.